# Remove XML root from SSIS scipt task

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

I am using the script task in SSIS Control flow task to save the output from the Execute SQL task to flat file destination. I tried the following script but did not succeed in getting the desired output

Script :-

```
string content = Dts.Variables["User::DataXML"].Value.ToString().Replace("<ROOT>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>").Replace("</ROOT>", "");
            string filePath = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString();

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
            writer.WriteLine(content);
            writer.Close();
```

Output in XML file :- 'Strict' ;

Required output :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<importemployee ............>
.....
.......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the script  :-

Only changes in :-

```
 string content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" + Dts.Variables["User::DataXML"].Value.ToString().Replace("<ROOT>", "").Replace("</ROOT>", "");
```